# Fit multiple images to parent height while maintaining its aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

How do I make these 3 images fit to its parent div height while maintaining the image's aspect ratio?

[image]

```
<div id="myM">
     <div class="ab">
        <img src="http://img42.com/2lWNS+" class="cd"/>
        <img src="http://img42.com/2lWNS+" class="cd"/>
        <img src="http://img42.com/2lWNS+" class="cd"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#myM{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
.ab{
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}
.cd{
    max-height:33%;
    width:auto;
}
```

Here is a [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/03cvpz24/)

Comment: Can i make some changes in html?

Comment: @ketan thanks. It depends but yes please show how you'd do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the float removing the container from the flow. Instead, you can make the container an inline-block and use right-align.

https://jsfiddle.net/9uyww2j0/2/

Without changing your HTML, my new CSS is this:

```
#myM{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: cyan;
    text-align: right;
}
.ab {
    display: inline-block; /* So text-align affects it */
    height: 100%
}
.cd{
    display: block; /* So takes full width */
    height:33%;
}
```